# Using log4net over web service

Tags: c#, web-services, log4net, syslog

I want to write a web service that is able send log data to syslog server.

Architecture is like this:

```
Client ---> Webservice ----> syslog server
```

Clients call the web service like this:

```
ServiceReference1.SysLogServiceClient clt = new ServiceReference1.SysLogServiceClient();
ServiceReference1.ClsSysLog temp = new ServiceReference1.ClsSysLog();
temp.date= DateTime.Now;
temp.time = DateTime.Now;
temp.processtype= "test";
temp.user= "testuser";
temp.application = "testapp";
bool result = clt.SendSysLog(temp);
```

Web service has a class and a function:

class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ClsSysLog
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime date{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime time { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string processtype { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string user { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string application { get; set; }    

}
```

Function:

```
private static readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

public bool SendSysLog(ClsSysLog SysLogItem)
{
    try
    {
        //date|time|processtype|user|application
        string msg = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}|{1:HH:mm:ss}|{2}|{3}|{4}|{5}|{6}", SysLogItem.date, SysLogItem.time, SysLogItem.processtype, SysLogItem.user, SysLogItem.application);
        Exception tempExt = new Exception();
        log.Info(msg, tempExt);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lastly the web service configuration is:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RemoteSyslogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender">
      <facility value="qradar" />
      <identity value=" %date{yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffzzz} %P{log4net:HostName} %P{app}" />
      <RemoteAddress value="192.168.1.55" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="   %P{pid}:%logger %m%n"   />
      <RemotePort value="514" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RealtimeMonitoringAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I do not know what the syslog server is doing, but by network sniffing tool, I see that it has no packet from 514 port.

Exception from the `log.Info(msg, tempExt)` function is

> System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

I cannot send syslog data to server by web service.

Comment: Please give the whole stacktrace of the exception...

Comment: why are you creating a new instance of Exception tempExt = new Exception(); whats the use of exception is here ?

Comment: Log.info method has two overrides one takes exeption type parameter. I thought that it is called as areference parameter. How can I get stactrace of the exception?

Comment: in log.Info, you dont need to pass exception as parameter because thats not necessary . And if you got exception , get the stacktrace  by calling ex.StackTrace in Catch.

Comment: I solved temporarily by using udp protocol. But tcp is needed for security. I will post answer if I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the issue but I notice in the config you have the wrong appender ref name. I would comment this rather than answer but I do not have the points :)

Comment: Which appender should be used?

Comment: I believe RemoteSyslogAppender should go there. That will tell L4N to use that appender.